# compare multiple cells in vba and return result for each comparision

Tags: excel, compare, vba

I input the values for 4 cells (A2 to A5) in sheet1, now the code should be in such a way that VBA takes the values from 4 cells in sheet1 and compare them to the cells from (A1 to D1) in sheet2 and should return the result in 4 cells in sheet2 (E2 to E5) in each cell stating match or does not match.

I have have been trying this from long time but able to use IF and THEN for all four times. Any use of loops or something that can change the code from like 30+ lines to few.

Comment: A2 to A6 represents 5 cells...

Comment: updated the question. Thanks

Comment: You have to show us any code you wrote to attempt to solve your problem...

Comment: @vamsikrishna - How do you wish to compare? `Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A1`, `Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!B1`, `Sheet1!A4=Sheet2!C1`, and `Sheet1!A5=Sheet2!D1`

Comment: @Pspl here is the code which i tried, the below code is for 2 worksheets but for only 1 cell, if I need for 4 cells then my idea is to repeat the IF condition 4 times which I believe is not a good coding practice
         Dim value1, value2 As String
                    If ParameterSheet.Range("B43").Value = OrigFile.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value Then
                        OutputFile.Worksheets("Summary").Range("D33").Value = "match"
                    Else
                        OutputFile.Worksheets("Summary").Range("D33").Value = "does not match"
           End If

Comment: @Mrig .. yes... i have to compare Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A1, Sheet1!A3=Sheet2!B1, Sheet1!A4=Sheet2!C1, and Sheet1!A5=Sheet2!D1 this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, destCell As Range
    Dim colIndex As Long

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'source sheet
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'destination sheet
    Set destCell = destSht.Range("D33")
    colIndex = 1

    For Each cel In srcSht.Range("A2:A5")   'loop through each cell in range srcSht.Range("A2:A5")
        If cel.Value = destSht.Cells(1, colIndex) Then  'check for match
            destCell.Offset(colIndex - 1, 0).Value = "Match"         'display result
        Else
            destCell.Offset(colIndex - 1, 0).Value = "No Match"      'display result
        End If
        colIndex = colIndex + 1
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou so much , this worked, but what if I want to display the result in sheet 2?

Comment: @vamsikrishna - Where exactly in `Sheet2`?

Comment: D33 to D36 in sheet 2

Comment: Thankyou so much, this works like a charm. I have been searching for this since 2 days. Now I will try to add this to my project. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello,I have another issue here. Actually for me `srcSht , destSht`  and other workbook which data need to be compared are 3 different workbooks. I was able to connect all three workbooks but the result in destSht only match even data in a cell does not match. HELP please @Mrig

Comment: @vamsikrishna - May I know the reason for unaccepting the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the forum and was stuck up with the above comment.  Accepting the answer. Thankyou.

Comment: @vamsikrishna - Give me sometime I'll update the answer as per your comment.

Comment: Thankyou :) @Mrig

Comment: I figured it out. Its working now.. Thankyou very much for the above code :) @Mrig